# CKeditor insertHtml/ insertElement IE8 issue

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

I have some problem with CKEditor insertHtml and insertElement methods under IE8, I've developed some custom plugin and when I try to insert any element into the text, in my case this is "span" tag with some extra custom attribute (where this custom tag value is base64_encode'd value)) it does not insert it in cursor position (as in FF or Chrome) but at the beginning of the text ...

Here are two examples how I use those both functions:

//1

```
editor.insertHtml("<span class='internal' internal='" + params + "'>" + data.url + "</span>")
```

//2

```
var span = editor.document.createElement( 'span' );

span.setAttribute( 'class', 'internal' );
span.setAttribute( 'internal', params );
span.setText( data.url );
editor.insertElement( span );
```

Any help ? :-)

Comment: You didn't provide any information when the span is being inserted (clicking, keystroke, automated code...). IEs are buggy and, most likely, you have a focus-related issue. Try calling `editor·focus()` before inserting the element. Also do a research where does the selection go with `editor.getSelection().getRanges()` before insertion (still, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish) and after it. Also add `editor.on( 'blur/focus', fn() )` listeners to watch what's going on with your instance.

Comment: Also note that `insertHtml` works fine with IE8 http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-01-21-08-51/full/samples/api.html

Comment: Cześć ;-) Span is inserted in onOK action in my dialog, I will try to do first some research on this focus, thank you

Comment: Ok, what I've found now is that IE8 does not get ranges, startOffset and endOffset params are '0' (it works fine in e.g. Chrome). Blur & Focus listener does fire, but I don't know what params do I have to look for there. My CKEditor version is 3.6.4 (problem with updating it is that this a part of very large cms, and it would require a lot of testing and stuff ;/ )

Comment: If you see caret on non-zero position and if editor *is focused* and if IE still returns selection with empty range at zero position, then something definitely is wrong with your copy of CKEditor. Check the same code on latest version.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I've updated it from 3.6.4 version to 4.0.1 ver. and it just started to work :-)